# can't seem to be able to use the icons that I specifically need

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

So I'm working on a webpage and for it I need to use some icons. There is a font file which contains said icons and I can use and display like 95% of them. Except for the ones I actually need to use. Because i can use most of the other icons, the font file is working fine. Can anyone here help me figure out what is going or with the other icons? I'm also not really sure how can show you what I mean, I can share my HTML code at least, so you get an idea of how I display those icons.

I use the FontDrop website to see what the names of the icons are and those names work for all icons, except the ones i have to use.

HTML:

```
<h1 class="icontextwhite"> <br><br><br><br>
 <i class="icon-email iconstylewhite"></i> 
 <br>
  2012
</h1>
```

The code above displays the 'email' icon, thats the name of the icon according to the read out from the website i mentioned above.

Below here is an example of the icon of a house, like a homescreen icon. Its called 'home', but when I want to display it, nothing shows.

```
<h1 class="icontextwhite"> <br><br><br><br>
 <i class="icon-home iconstylewhite"></i> 
 <br>
  2012
</h1>
```

Comment: Are you sure your icon font actually contains a home icon?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) . See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Without having a working snippet which includes the font you are using I don't see how we can help you.